# Drupal Migration - Error 404's

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I've set up a Drupal 7 site locally and have ftp'd the site over to my ISP's server which is a linux box running PHP and MySQL.

I've never successfully logged into the site before and I have locked myself out.  When I go http://www.example.com/?q=user and click on request New Password then I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /user/password was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

One thing I've been confused about and that is the .htaccess file.  I never had one locally on my Mac and I did not need it (I know it is hidden) - so I downloaded one and deployed it to the web site but then I got 500 errors, it made it worse.  I've since deleted that file and at least I get some content - but not very much - just the front page.  I overrode the themes name in settings.php as I have user access errors there. I changed it back to one of the default themes and that allowed me to get some content and not the 'white screen of death'

Advice welcome!

Comment: I would try to answer this, except it will inevitably get moved to [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) (unless you move it first... hint). ;)

Comment: Am I best deleting and posting there, was not aware of that site?  Can't see how to move?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant... Sorry. Should have been more clear. :)